# python prototype structure, not working

Tags: python, prototype

whenever i print the c1 object, it prints:
    <**main**.Car object at 0x7fde8b29a240>

however i added the **str** method, to format it to a proper string, why is it not printing a readable string?

```
import copy


class Prototype:

    def __init__(self):
        # constructor method to create the object
        self._objects = {}

     def register_object(self, name, obj):
        # this method is used to register an object
        self._objects[name] = obj

     def unregister_object(self, name):
         # this method is used to unregister an object
         del self._objects[name]

     def clone(self, name, **attr):

         obj = copy.deepcopy(self._objects.get(name))
         obj.__dict__.update(attr)
         return obj


class Car:
     def __init__(self):
     self.name = "Skylark"
     self.color = "blue"
     self.options = "extra horsepower in engine"

     def __str__(self):

        return '{} | {} | {}'.format(self.name, self.color, self.options)


c = Car()
prototype = Prototype()
prototype.register_object('skylark',c)


c1 = prototype.clone('skylark')

print(c1)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Your code also throws an IndentationError. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem too. And I don't understand why do you need Prototype class in this example provided that you have a problem with the Car class

Comment: This is an example of the prototype, code structure, please look up different coding structures for more information. I'm simple unaware of why, my object is not printing a readable string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the indentation in your code. I've corrected this and can get the desired answer too. The indentation is a bit off for the function `def`s. in both the classes.

I've called this file as **test.py**

```
import copy


class Prototype:

    def __init__(self):
        # constructor method to create the object
        self._objects = {}

    def register_object(self, name, obj):
    # this method is used to register an object
        self._objects[name] = obj

    def unregister_object(self, name):
         # this method is used to unregister an object
        del self._objects[name]

    def clone(self, name, **attr):

        obj = copy.deepcopy(self._objects.get(name))
        obj.__dict__.update(attr)
        return obj


class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Skylark"
        self.color = "blue"
        self.options = "extra horsepower in engine"

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} | {} | {}'.format(self.name, self.color, self.options)


c = Car()
prototype = Prototype()
prototype.register_object('skylark',c)


c1 = prototype.clone('skylark')

print(c1)
```

When I run the file

```
$ python test.py
```

The output is:

```
#Output: Skylark | blue | extra horsepower in engine
```